# How can I resize an uploaded image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I am currently using this code so users can upload images to my site

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png','.jpeg','.JPG','.PNG','.BIF','.GIF','.JPEG'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
$max_filesize = 524288; //  filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
$uploadpath = "/home/path/to/file/files/avatars/$_SESSION[user]";
$posted9 = hash('md5',$_SESSION["user"]).$ext; /* not for security mind you. */
// Upload the file to your specified path.
        $f = file_put_contents(
            $upload_path . $posted9,
            file_get_contents('php://input')
            );
        if($f)
    $m="Avatar updated<br/>"; // It worked.
  else
     $m="There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again."; // It failed :(.
```

However, when the images are rezised to fit inside the comments on my website, they become distorted and lose their quality.
[image]

How using PHP can I resize the images so that the quality is maintained?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials and samples on Google. Did you even bother to research it? There are also countless questions of that type on StackOverflow too...

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/imagecopyresampled

Comment: You're asking about resizing images, but only show code for uploading images... and find a better method for testing filetype than a long array of case-sensitive file extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// Url of the file
$url = "/homepages/0/d502303335/htdocs/foo.jpg";

// Set a maximum height and width, I used the ones on your picture
$width = 49;
$height = 47;


// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($url);

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output, You can use another url, In my case i just overwrite the picture
imagejpeg($image_p, $url);

?>
```

Here's the result:

http://www.filmgratuiti.org/varie/cenBqHxMD90Q2.jpg


Much more better then your's

[image]

So basically after you have uploaded the file you run my code and you are good to go

Answer (score 1):

```
   public function resize($width,$height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image;
  }
```

https://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled